# TypeError: $scope.lstLaptop.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I'm trying to make a simple form for insert, delete, update using localStorage to store my data. When I click Add button, It shows an error

> TypeError: $scope.lstLaptop.push is not a function.

I was back to my code and check syntax if I'm wrong, but I think my code was only 3 lines and look usual. Can you tell me what I was missing something or what the problem really was from?

Just ignored my other code and check my controller lapCreateUpdateCtrl please, I'm out of idea what I'm wrong.

### HTML file:

```
    <div class="container">

        <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Laptop Model</th>
                <th>Price($)</th>
                <th>Option</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat = "laptops in lstLaptop track by $index">
                <td><p ng-bind = laptops.model></p></td>
                <td><p ng-bind = laptops.price></p></td>
                <td><button type="button" ng-click="remove1($index)" 
                            class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                      Delete
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" ng-click="edit1($index)"
                            class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">
                      Edit
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" ng-click="update1($index)"
                            class="btn btn-info btn-xs">
                      Update
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
                ng-click="save()">
          Save
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

### app.JS file:

```
routerApp.controller('lapCreateUpdateCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.laptop = {};
    $scope.lstLaptop = [];
    function init(){
        var strLaptop = window.localStorage.getItem("LAPTOP_KEY");
        if(strLaptop){
            $scope.lstLaptop = JSON.parse(strLaptop);
        }
    }
    init();
    $scope.add1 = function(){
        $scope.lstLaptop.push($scope.laptop);
        $scope.laptop = {};
    }
    $scope.remove1 = function(index){
        $scope.lstLaptop.splice(index,1);
        alert("Deleted!");
    }
    $scope.edit1 = function(index){
        $scope.laptop = angular.copy($scope.lstLaptop[index]);
    }
    $scope.update1 = function(index){
        $scope.lstLaptop.splice(index, 1, $scope.laptop);
        $scope.laptop = {};
    }
    $scope.save=function(){
        window.localStorage.setItem("LAPTOP_KEY", JSON.stringify($scope.lstLaptop));
    }

}]);
```

---

I want content input from textbox

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="laptop.model" id="model" name="model"
        placeholder="Model" required />
 <input type="number" ng-model="laptop.price" id="price" name="price"
        placeholder="Price" required />
 <button type="button" ng-click="add()">
   Add Desktop
 </button>
```

Comment: What line is causing that error? And what is the contents of `$scope.lstLaptop` when that error occurs?

Comment: **I want content input  from textbox**
`<input type="text" ng-model="laptop.model" id="model" name="model" placeholder="Model" required />            
<input type="number" ng-model="laptop.price" id="price" name="price" placeholder="Price" required />
<button type="button" ng-click="add()">Add Desktop</button>`

Comment: When I start to click an add button, error appear and the error said
_TypeError: $scope.lstLaptop.push is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.add (app.js:168)_

Comment: Value like _Model_ and _Price_? I input it and then click add button.
I have declared `$scope.laptop` that my input type was `ng-model=laptop.model`

Comment: The error states that **`$scope.lstLaptop.push` is not a function**. So what is the value of `$scope.lstLaptop` when that error occurs?

Comment: I don't understand, which value? I'm very new here

Comment: The likely cause of the error is that `$scope.lstLaptop` is being assigned a value other than an array reference. The major suspect is the assignment statement in the `init` function.

Comment: @LaCooler have a look into my answer. as I have described, you are overriding the variable in your init fuction.

Comment: I appreciate you guys for helping me. It's worked now. I'm not sure what wrong but I've been rewriting it again so it working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have called `init()` and then inside that function, you have changed the `$scope.lstLaptop` to an object. When `$scope.add1` will be called, it will throw an error as object does not have push function. It only works with Arrays.

I don't understand what you want to achieve, but you can do something like below. It will retain the `lstLaptop` as array

```
function init(){
        var strLaptop = window.localStorage.getItem("LAPTOP_KEY");
        if(strLaptop){
            $scope.lstLaptop.push(JSON.parse(strLaptop));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't do anything. Even I click upvote, it still down.